# Grails keeps accessing H2 instead of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, grails

I'm taking grails for a spin and my first try is to access an existing Postgres database. For this I've created a model, a scaffolding controller and modified the DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "postgres"
    password = "postgres"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dh2"
        }
    }
}
```

Grails, however, keeps trying to connect to H2.

```
    Line | Method
->>  344 | getJdbcSQLException       in org.h2.message.DbException
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    178 | get                       in     ''
|    154 | get . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   5213 | readTableOrView           in org.h2.command.Parser
|   1220 | readTableFilter . . . . . in     ''
|   1859 | parseSelectSimpleFromPart in     ''
|   1968 | parseSelectSimple . . . . in     ''
|   1853 | parseSelectSub            in     ''
|   1674 | parseSelectUnion . . . .  in     ''
|   1662 | parseSelect               in     ''
|    434 | parsePrepared . . . . . . in     ''
|    306 | parse                     in     ''
|    278 | parse . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    243 | prepareCommand            in     ''
|    442 | prepareLocal . . . . . .  in org.h2.engine.Session
|    384 | prepareCommand            in     ''
|   1188 | prepareCommand . . . . .  in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
|     73 | <init>                    in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement
|    276 | prepareStatement . . . .  in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
|     15 | $tt__index                in nl.softworks.dh2grails.UserController
|    189 | doFilter . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any suggestions what is going wrong here?

Comment: An complicating twist; I changed the dataSource to use H2 and to start creating tables:        
development {    dataSourceH2 {
            dbCreate = "create"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }, but it does not create the table: Table "user" not found

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the db naming has anything to do with it, but maybe try to change it from testDb to devDb. I'm new to Grails myself and i'm not sure if it's wired this way for a reason with the naming. Here's a copy of one that is working for me, I am using H2 for development and will migrate to Postgres or MySQL once I am finished with development:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }
}
```

I'm curious if that testDb changed to devDb will make a difference.

Comment: Tried it, but of course it did not make a difference. I would have walked away if that was the cause.

Comment: it generates the db file with name as devDb

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally in the dark on the cause, but I created a new grails qotd application (as it is described in my book) and that ran (against H2). Then I copied the models and controllers over from my first attempt, and that also ran (against H2). Then I copied the DataSource.groovy over and restarted; Grails then started to access Postgres, and I had to configure all kind of id stuff to get it up correctly. Now it is running...